# Train a deep learning model with input as a vector and predicts as a vector?

Tags: deep-learning, python

I am trying to build a Deep Learning model that takes a numeric vector $X$ of dimension $1 \times 50$ and predicts a numeric vector $y$ of dimension $1 \times 50$.

It's a linear regression problem. I am trying to achieve the coefficients/weights that can help me

Code I used:

```
X = np.array(...) // array of 50 features and 5 sample vectors (shape of X is 5x50)
y = np.array(...) // array of 50 features (shape of y is 5x50)
model = Sequential([Dense(1, input_shape=[5,50])])

optimizer = Adam(0.001)

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mae', 'mse'])

model.fit(X,y, epochs=250, validation_split=0.25))
```

So, basically we are achieving `X*w ~ y` where $w$ is the weights/coefficients that we want to identify using DL.

Programmatically, I tried using the same logic and calculated $w = y . X^{-1}$ for all the vectors. Took average of the coeff and applied on the test data.

Comment: What exactly is your doubt? Are you asking whether your procedure is correct or nor?

Comment: I am asking for procedure on how to achieve it as I am unable to achieve proper results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I can see there is a problem in your third line of code. `input_shape` should be the shape of the input to the network, not the shape of your training data.
If your training data has the shape of 5x50 you would have 5 training samples in your dataset.
For this to work your input has to be 50:

```
model = Sequential([Dense(1, input_shape=[50])])
```

Now with `model.summary()` you can check that the input of your network is `(None, 50)`.

Also note that in a neural network, each neuron has an activation function.
Depending on the activation function $f(z)$ , the output would be $y = f(b+W^TX)$ which is not the same as linear regression.

Hope this helps!